# Get with Flutter a nested JSON from Firebase DataSnapshot

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I use flutter with package firebase_database. With the code

```
final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _newsList = new List();

  _newsQuery = _database
     .reference()
     .child('news')
     .orderByChild('published')
     .limitToFirst(10);

  _newsQuery.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
}

_onEntryAdded(Event event) {
  setState(() {
    News n = News.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    _newsList.add(n);
  });
}
```

i get a perfect list `_newsList` of all queried items. The news class is

```
 import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

 class News {
   String key;
   String image;
   String text;
   String title;
   String published;

   News(this.image, this.text, this.published);

   News.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) :
     key = snapshot.key,
     text = snapshot.value["text"],
     title = snapshot.value["title"],
     image = snapshot.value["image"],
     published = snapshot.value["published"];

   toJson() {
     return {
     "image": image,
     "text": text,
     "title": title,
     "published": published,
   };
  }
}
```

The json-structure in the database is:

```
database
|__news
    |__post1
    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum"
    |    |__title: "Title of post"
    |
    |__post2
         |__ ...
```

Now i want to load a nested json-structure from the database with

```
database
|__news
    |__category1
    |    |
    |    |__post1
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 1"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post1"
    |    |__post2
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 2"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post2"
    |    |__description: "description text"
    |    |__id: "id of category"
    |    .
    |    .
    |
    |__category2
    |    |
    |    |__post34
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 34"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post34"
    |    .
    |    .
```

I try to find a solution to load the nested DataSnapshots into  class, but i always get exceptions. The best code i tried so far is

```
 class News {
   final List<Category> categories;

   News({this.categories});

   factory News.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

   List<dynamic> listS = snapshot.value;

   listS.forEach((value) =>
     print('V $value')
   );

   List<Category> list = listS.map((i) => Category.fromJson(i)).toList();

   return News(
     categories: list
   );

 }
```

But this throws the exception

E/flutter ( 5882): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'
E/flutter ( 5882): #0      new News.fromSnapshot. (package:app/models/news.dart:23:55)
E/flutter ( 5882): #1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414:29)
E/flutter ( 5882): #2      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219:19)

I found in flutter and dart no code-example to load nested json with DataSnapshot. Do you know any code-sample?

If you want to see my full code, then look at https://github.com/matthiaw/gbh_app. The not working part is the nested json in calendar at https://github.com/matthiaw/gbh_app/blob/4de0f20f6162801db86ef6644609829c27a4dd76/lib/models/calendar.dart

Comment: Please add a sample JSON returned data for both query results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also looking on how to handle nested json objects in Flutter with Cloud Firestore and found your post. As I solved my problem, maybe it helps you too: In the "fromJson"-factory of my model I had to parse every element in the list with jsonEncode and jsonDecode before adding it to the model.

in the DatabaseService:

```
Future<LocationRecordings> getLocationRecordings(String location) async {
 DocumentReference document = locationRecordingsCollection.document((location));

 DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =  await document.get();
 var data = LocationRecordings.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data);
 return data;
}
```

in the model:

```
factory LocationRecordings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
 List<Recording> recList = [];

 List<dynamic>.from(json['recordings']).forEach((content) {
      Recording recording = Recording.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(content)));
      recList.add(recording);
   });
 return new LocationRecordings(recordings: recList, state: json['state']);
}
```